# How to pick an encryption algorithm (cipher) and mode for PHP's mcrypt, for encrypting passwords?

Tags: encryption, php, algorithm

There are numerous algorithms listed in the PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

How strong is each one and what criteria to use when picking one?

Also the [mcrypt_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) function requires `mode` to be passed. From their docs:

> One of the `MCRYPT_MODE_modename` constants, or one of the following
>   strings: "ecb", "cbc", "cfb", "ofb", "nofb" or "stream".

Again, what criteria to use on choosing a mode?

Comment: This question is too broad. We need to know what kind of operations you'll do that require crypto (e.g. we don't all use the same algorithms for encrypting drives, encrypting IM messages, etc.), and the capabilities of your clients also matter.

Comment: See my answer to [Strongest cryptographic algorithm available in PHP 5.3](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26289/strongest-cryptographic-algorithm-available-in-php-5-3)

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to encrypt passwords as that opens the door to them being stolen. Instead you want to hash them, a one-way operation is mathematically impossible (or at least very hard) to reverse. This means that stealing password hashes will never lead to stealing passwords.

PHP has a great set of functions for this: [password_hash](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Just use them with the default values and you'll get state of the art technology automatically. See [this reference](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) for background.

Comment: Generally yes. In this scenario however I need two way encryption.